# Writing a simple for loop in Swift results in error

Tags: swift

I have the following code:

```
let something = 5

for (var i = 1; i< something; i++)
{

}
```

I get the following error:

braced block in unused closure!!

There is something wrong with the "something" variable I am using above. Any ideas?

```
UPDATE:
```

And this works:

```
 for var i = 1; i<=noOfTimes;i++
    {
        println("Hello World")
    }
```

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the fact that your first example has a closure with no actual code in it?

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop, put a space between `i` and `<` or remove the space between `<` and `something`. The good syntaxes are: `i < something` and `i<something`.

This is the result of some powerful features in Swift: [prefix, postfix & compound operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID46).

Comment: @Zaph Well, it's defined that way in the Swift book; see the bit about whitespace in the Operators section of the [Lexical Structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-XID_861) chapter. It's the  way the compiler determines the difference between a postfix operator and a binary operator here (as in Swift, "i<" might be "i" with the postfix operator "<" applied.)

Comment: The point is that it is a poor language design when such a minor change causes a major change in program execution. It is a flaw in the design of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Swift supports two syntaxes for `for`:

```
for <identifier> in <collection> { <statements> }
```

or

```
for <initialization>; <condition>; <increment> { <statements> }
```

Neither of them require parenthesis around the `for` specification.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between i and <.  The following works.

```
let something = 5

for (var i = 1; i < something; i++)
{

}
```